# Case when Statements implementation in Informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-cloud

Could anyone help me with writing below case statements in expression transformation in  Informatica PowerCenter?

```
Case      When STATUS_REASON_CODE in ( 'BI Complete' , 'BI Updated', 'BI Complete') and Outcome__c is null and BI_Outcome__c is null then 'PA Required'
              when STATUS_REASON_CODE in ( 'BI Complete' , 'BI Updated', 'BI Complete') and Outcome__c is null 
                                      Then Decode (BI_Outcome__c, 'PA Appeal Pending', 'PA Appeal Required','PA Pending','PA Required',BI_Outcome__c)
                when  STATUS_REASON_CODE in ('PA Appeal Approved', 'PA Approved') and Outcome__c is null  Then 'Approved'
                  when  STATUS_REASON_CODE in('PA Appeal Denied', 'PA Denied') and Outcome__c is null  Then 'Denied'
                  when Outcome__c='PA Pending' then 'PA Required'
                  When Outcome__c='PA Appeal Pending' then 'PA Appeal Required'
                   when  STATUS_REASON_CODE in ('PA Appeal Approved', 'PA Approved') and Outcome__c is null  Then 'Approved'
                  when  STATUS_REASON_CODE in('PA Appeal Denied', 'PA Denied') and Outcome__c is null  Then 'Denied'
         else Outcome__c end
```

Comment: Except last two when clause which are duplicate of 3rd and 4th when clause, what is the other issue with your code? What is expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any issue at all. This seems to me nested if-else statement. You can implement yourself using below guide -

```
 IIF ( IN(STATUS_REASON_CODE,'BI Complete' , 'BI Updated', 'BI Complete' ) AND and Outcome__c is null and BI_Outcome__c is null, 'PA Required',
  IIF (STATUS_REASON_CODE in ( 'BI Complete' , 'BI Updated', 'BI Complete') and Outcome__c is null , 
   IIF(BI_Outcome__c = 'PA Appeal Pending', 'PA Appeal Required', 
    IIF(BI_Outcome__c = 'PA Pending','PA Required',BI_Outcome__c)...
```

Of course this is not complete and you need to complete it. This looks complex but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Nested IIF is one option - for readability I prefer using a DECODE, like:

```
DECODE(True,
    Condition_1, Value_1,
    Condition_2, Value_2,
    ....
Default)
```

So, this would in your case start like:

```
DECODE(True,
    IN(STATUS_REASON_CODE,'BI Complete' , 'BI Updated', 'BI Complete' ) AND and Outcome__c is null and BI_Outcome__c is null, 'PA Required',
    STATUS_REASON_CODE in ( 'BI Complete' , 'BI Updated', 'BI Complete') and Outcome__c is null, ....
    ...
    )
```